# FORTRAN error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I'm new to FORTRAN, and getting this error #6404.

```
my_file.f(11): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.
[POTENCIAL]      d=POTENCIAL(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.4,1.4)
```

This is with the ifort compiler, and I hope it is not a compiler bug.

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

```
  program iiuu
  implicit none
  REAL*8 d
  d=POTENCIAL(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.4,1.4)
  write(*,*) 'potential=', d
  END program iiuu

  FUNCTION POTENCIAL(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6)
  REAL*8 R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,V2,V3,V4
  DIMENSION R(6)
  R(1)=R1
  R(2)=R2
  R(3)=R3
  R(4)=R4
  R(5)=R5
  R(6)=R6
  V2=V2BODY(R)
  V3=V3BODY(R)
  V4=V4BODY(R)
  POTENCIAL=V2+V3+V4+VADD(R)
  RETURN
  END

  FUNCTION V2BODY(R)
  .....
  .....
```

Answer (score 16):

No, it is not a compiler bug. Here's an edit of your code which has at least a chance of compiling:

```
program iiuu
  implicit none
  REAL*8 d
  d=POTENCIAL(1.0d0,1.0d0,1.0d0,1.0d0,1.4d0,1.4d0)
  write(*,*) 'potential=', d

  contains

  real*8 FUNCTION  POTENCIAL(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6)
  REAL*8 R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,V2,V3,V4
  real*8, DIMENSION(6) :: R
  R(1)=R1
  R(2)=R2
  R(3)=R3
  R(4)=R4
  R(5)=R5
  R(6)=R6
  V2=V2BODY(R)
  V3=V3BODY(R)
  V4=V4BODY(R)
  POTENCIAL=V2+V3+V4+VADD(R)
  END function potencial

  END program iiuu
```

1. Your `potencial` function did not have a return type (which is the original error message you came across)
2. It did not return anything (`return` statement was not necessary)
3. At the call point compiler had no idea where to look for the function. Either package your functions into `modules` and `use` them, or use `contains` statement, like in the example above
4. `1.0` is single-precision. Use `1.d0` to tell the compiler it's a double precision number
5. Why on earth do you send six numbers instead of having an array as an argument of the `potencial` function?

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work. 
    Just changed it to  correct data type representation.
    The rest still the same.

Comment: I'd like to raise yours rating, but cant do it - haven't enough posts yet.

Comment: @user1092021 - If it answers your question you can click on the checkmark to raise the rating. That's considered appropriate.

Comment: Answer to #5. Actually I don't know who did it 20 years ago, I just had to fix it for my wife's research in a chemistry. it's contains 40 pages of code, and rewriting this code isn't cost effective.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work. 
Just changed it to  correct data type representation.
The rest still the same.

```
program iiuu
IMPLICIT none
REAL*8 d, POTENCIAL
d=POTENCIAL(1.0d0,1.0d0,1.0d0,1.0d0,1.4d0,1.4d0)  
write(*,*) 'potential=', d
END program iiuu

FUNCTION POTENCIAL(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6)
IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
DIMENSION R(6)
R(1)=R1
R(2)=R2
......
......
```